# problem in display two fields of join with same name in Laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have two tables in MySql datebase:

```
person('id', 'name', 'address')
car('id', 'person_id', 'name')
```

I join them with this query:

`$data = DB::table('person')->join('car', 'person.id', '=', 'car.person_id')->get(); return view('view1',['data'=>$data]);`

in view1 we have:

```
person name: {{$data->name}}
car name: {{$data->name}}
```

the question is how can I show these two fields in view1?
notice that I can't change the fields name to two different names in my case.

Comment: $data = DB::table('person')->select('car.name as carName','person.name as personName')
->join('car', 'person.id', '=', 'car.person_id')->get();

Comment: i suggest you to create model for each table.it saves lots of time and code clean

Comment: You should read about laravel relationships. A person has many cars hasMany and car belongsTo person. Then read about with. Model::with('relationship_name')

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create models for each table using `php artisan` commands

```
php artisan make:model Person
```

Person model look like below

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "person";

    public function cars()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
}
```

Similarly create car model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="car";


   
}
```

To Fetch you can do like this

```
$person=Person::with('cars')->get();
```

So you don't need alias

```
$data = DB::table('person')->select('car.name as carName','person.name as personName') ->join('car', 'person.id', '=', 'car.person_id')->get();
```